# Could not load type from assembly error during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an `asp.net mvc 5` application. On my dev and uat machine the application works just fine but when i deployed to the staging machine the applications throws the error "Could not load type from assembly" whenever the code tries to access a particular method in an assembly.

The solution that contains the web application has three projects and one of the projects contains the the type that is throwing the

> > System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'TypeName' from assembly 'AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I have checked to confirm that the correct version is being loaded, i have checked GAC the assembly is not loaded form there, I'v update the version on .net framework on the server, I have deleted temporary asp.net files and restarted `IIS` but nothing has worked. I even copied the same application folder to other servers on our network and set it up in `IIS`; it works perfectly on other servers but on staging server, it doesn't work.

I have spent 2 days now googling and searching on SO; and trying different things but i'm yet to find a solution to the problem. Any suggestion that would point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if there's no assembly redirect in your web.config?

Comment: Yes I have. There's no redirect.

Comment: FusionLog - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net